# What is the name of the icon for Google Maps street view?

Tags: google-maps

What is the name of the icon for Google Maps street view?
It is orange and modeled on a man. (Today he wears an uniform with a ball for World Cup):

[image: WA62533 question example]

Is it called just a stickman?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Pegman](http://maps.google.co.nz/intl/en/help/maps/streetview/learn/pegman.html) comes in a variety of styles, eg:

[image: WA62533 example]

Comment: I am the peg man. Koo-koo-ka-choo.